# Best way to manage train/test/val splits on AzureML

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm currently using AzureML with pretty complex workflows involving large datasets etc. and I'm wondering what is the best way to manage the splitting resulting of preprocessing steps. All my projects are built as pipelines fed by registered Datasets. I want to be able to track the splitting in order to easily retrieve, for example, test and validation sets for integration testing purposes.

What would be the best pattern to apply there ? Registering every intermediate set as different Dataset ? Directly retrieving the intermediate sets using the Run IDs ? ...

Thaanks

Comment: are you using the SDK or the UI to create your Pipelines?

Answer (score 2):

I wish I had a more coherent answer, the upside is that you're at the bleeding edge so, should you find a pattern that works for you, you can evangelize it and make it best practice! Hopefully you find my rantings below valuable.

First off -- if you aren't already, you should definitely use `PipelineData` to as the intermediate artifact for passing data b/w `PipelineStep`s. In this way, you can treat the `PipelineData` as semi-ephemeral in that they are materialized should you need them, but that it isn't a requirement to have a hold on every single version of every `PipelineData`. You can always grab them using Azure Storage Explorer, or like you said, using the SDK and walking down from a `PipelineRun` object.

Another recommendation is to split your workflow into the following pipelines:

- featurization pipeline (all joining, munging, and featurizing)
- training pipeline
- scoring pipeline (if you have a batch score scenario).

The intra-pipeline artifacts are `PipelineData`, and the inter-pipeline artifacts would be registered Datasets.

To actually get actual your question of associating data splits together with a models, our team struggled with this -- especially because for each train,test,split we also have an "extra cols" which contains either identifiers or leaking variables that  that the model shouldn't see.

In our current <s>hack</s> implementation, we register our "gold" dataset as an Azure ML Dataset at the end of the featurization pipeline. The first step of our training pipline is a `PythonScriptStep`, "Split Data", which contains our train,test,split steps and outputs a pickled dictionary as `data.pkl`. Then we can unpickle anytime we need one of the splits and can join back using the index using for any reporting needs. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/swanderz/1be3fb9a9f8eb4eca42a8b0d76c7861b).

Comment: Hey Anders ! Thanks a lot for the answers. This definitely helps. I'm already indeed using the `PipelineData` to persist intermediate data into run's folders. After this discussion, I think using `Run-IDs` and a `PipelineRun` object to walk-down the structure when needed is what makes the more sense. I like a lot the `dict` idea, it's a good way to centralize everything and retrieve data easily out of preprocessing steps. Thanks a lot for the answers !

Answer (score 1):

Registration is to make sharing and reuse easier so that you can retrieve the dataset by its name. If you do expect to reuse the test/validation sets in other experiments, then registering them make sense. However, if you are just trying to keep records of what you used for this particular experiment, you can always find those info via Run as you suggested.

Comment: I agree with @May_Hu in that registering artifacts is only valuable if 1) the data doesn't change very frequently and 2) you need to provision that data for other data scientists or other experiments. In other cases you can get by with using `PipelineDataset` as the output.

Comment: Hi both ! Thanks a lot for the answers. I indeed need to allow re-usage of the train/test/val splits for further "after-deployment" integration testing etc. My goal is to limit as much as possible the number of Dataset I register to avoid proliferation of low-value datasets available. Currently I'm indeed passing some .csv from a pipeline step to another using yaml input/outputs. I understood those are generating handy path from my workspace's blob to upload the files to. Any snippet available for easily retrieve those files from outside of the run ?